# How to initialize and draw a Rectangle variable in a paintComponent method?

Tags: java, swing, variables, graphics, paintcomponent

I've been trying to add collision to my game, it seemed like a piece of cake, I already know how to **draw** a rectangle. But I need that rectangle to be represented by something, a variable. But it seems like there's no method like **g.drawRect(myRectangleVariable)**. I need to do some if statements checking for intersection but if I don't have a rectangle variable then what do I compare? If you guys need any of my code just tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do

```
g.drawRect(myRectangleVariable.x, 
           myRectangleVariable.y, 
           myRectangleVariable.width, 
           myRectangleVariable.height);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still pretty new to graphics so I still don't know all of it's possibilities.

Comment: Youre welcome. In general look to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) first. Then see what info you have from your `Rectangle` object. All options will become apparent :)

Comment: You know, I do before every question I ask, but I guess I'm too stupid to find the answer I'm looking for in the javadocs.

Answer (score 2):

So create a variable to hold your `Rectangle` :p

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
g.drawRect(rect);
```

Comment: If you know the coordinates (x, y) and the (width, height), then yeah! Have a look at the official docs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use 2D Shape objects like rectangle;

Like:

```
    Graphics g = // get your graphic object from Component
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
    g2d.draw(rect);
```

Benefits: You will get many features like finding intersection and other fancy 2D things.

Answer (score 0):

First, create your rectangle variable like this (Just put in the coordinates and size of the rectangle in the Rectangle parameter) :

`Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height)`

Next, use graphics2D to draw it. Use the g2d.draw() function as the drawRect() function doesn't accept a rectangle.

`g2d.drawRect(rectangle)`

That is how you do it.

The benefit of doing this rather than just using the drawRect() function is that you can use the rectangle as the button as you can just check if the mouse is in the rectangle and has clicked it. Then you can change things on the rectangle (such as size) to make it more fancy and interesting.

P.S. If you don't understand the mouse part just search up MouseMotionListener and MouseListener.